# "Error initializing complex filters" Using volume filter in fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Thanks to the answers i got on my last [question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/36547/how-to-add-a-afade-effect-to-a-complex-filter-in-this-case-volume), i came up with the following if statement named `string` :
`"if(between(t,6,12.6)+between(t,16.6,29.8)+between(t,33.8,44),0.15,if(between(t,5,6),0.15/(6-5)*(t-5),if(between(t,15.6,16.6),0.15/(16.6-15.6)*(t-15.6),if(between(t,32.8,33.8),0.15/(33.8-32.8)*(t-32.8),if(between(t,12.6,13.6),0.15/(13.6-12.6)*(13.6-t),if(between(t,29.8,30.8),0.15/(30.8-29.8)*(30.8-t),if(between(t,44,45),0.15/(45-44)*(45-t))))))))"`

And i'm applying it in the following fluent-ffmpeg command thanks to this complex filter :

```js
.complexFilter([
    {
        filter: "volume",
        options: [string], 
        inputs: "1",
        outputs: 'audio',
        eval: 'frame'
    },
    {
        filter: "amix",
        options: 'inputs=2',
        inputs: ["0:a", "audio"]
    }
])
```

What this does is just like -filter_complex "[1:a]volume=`string`:eval=frame["audio"]" then it applies an amix on 0:a and audio. I'm getting the following errors though :

```
[Parsed_volume_0 @ 0x7fffe828d140] [Eval @ 0x7ffff0835170] Missing ')' or too many args in 'between(t'
[Parsed_volume_0 @ 0x7fffe828d140] Error when evaluating the volume expression '"if(between(t'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fffe81e0400] Error initializing filter 'volume' with args '"if(between(t'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Comment: I tried your volume expression in the pure ffmpeg command, and it works, i.e. **it is syntactically correct** (but silence in first 5 seconds). So the problem is in the *fluent ffmpeg* part (I have no experience with it), for example you entered incorrect value in `options: [string]` (maybe braces have been part of the `string` variable itself – I only guess).

Comment: Ok i also tried and it seems like it works just in ffmpeg. Except it's not doing what i want, at all. Must have made an error somewhere. Between 6 to 12.6, 16,6 to 29.8 and 33.8 to 44 it should be at 15%. Before each of those it should decrease from 100% to 15% over 1s and after each of those it should increase to 100% over 1s.
The rest of the time it should be at 100%. I'm gonna figure out why the fluent version isn't working but i have no idea why my if statement is wrong.

Comment: Ok i managed to fix my fluent-ffmpeg command. But for some reason, no filter is applied when i use it. Even though there is one when i just use the ffmpeg command.

Comment: I would prefer to construct your volume expression by continuing the procedure in my answer to your previous question – it is a safe way. Then, if it will work, you may optimize it.

Comment: Or use directly the ready-to-use expression in the comment of Баяр Гончикжапов under my answer of your previous question.